# Can you find the z component in this system?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, systems-of-equations

I will use uppercase letters to denote known variables and lowercase letters to denote unkown ones.

Assume I have a vector $<X', Y', z'>$, and an invertible matrix $T$, and a vector $<x,y,z>$ constrained to a known plane $P=(N,V)$ ($N$ being the normal and $V$ being a point in the plane).

We know that $<X', Y', z'> = T\times<x,y,z>$.

Is it possible to either find $z'$ or $<x,y,z>$ in this system?

Comment: Wouldn't you need to know either $T$, or $x$ and $y$ to answer this question?

Comment: You do know $T$, it's an uppercase variable.

Comment: Then yes, it is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the fact that $r = (x,y,z)$ lies in the plane you get:
$$N^T(r-V)= 0$$
From the other equation you have:
$$q = Tr$$
Where $q = (X', Y', z')$. Note that $T$ is invertible so the equations are not linearly dependent. Then ultimately you get 4 equations for 4 unknowns.